# Matrix conversion in MatLab

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix

I have a sample matrix in MatLab

```
>> A=[0 0 0 0; 5 1 4 6; 10 87 74 34]

A =

     0     0     0     0
     5     1     4     6
    10    87    74    34
```

and I want to create a new vector which will have the elements of A without the first column. In addition, each element(starting from line 1, column 2) will be placed in only one column. So the target vector is the following.

```
newdata=

        0
        0
        0
        1
        4
        6
        87
        74
        34
```

I created an `m-file` that it's suppossed to do it but all I get is a vector

```
newdata=

        34
        34
        34
        34
        34
        34
        34
        34
        34
```

My code is

```
newdata=zeros(size(A,1)*(size(A,2)-1),1);
for ii=1:size(A,1)
    for jj=2:size(A,2)
        for n=1:(size(A,1)*(size(A,2)-1))
            newdata(n)=A(ii,jj);
        end
    end
end
```

I understand that it's something trivial, but I can't find my mistake.
Any help is really welcomed!

Comment: Other than not being idiomatic Matlab, the mistake in your code is that you perform the `n`-loop for each pair of indices `ii` and `jj`. I.e. you fill in all of `newdata` for each iteration of `ii` and `jj`. Instead of looping over `n`, you should calculate `n` as a function of `ii` and `jj`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your mistake is you have written `n` as the innermost loop and thats why `newdata` is getting overwritten again and again for each element (of course, except the first column entries). Secondly, this is an exteremely inefficient way. You should take advantage of MATLAB's `colon` operator. This can be done as follows:

```
A=A(:,2:end);  %removing first column
A=A.';
newdata=A(:); %collapsing it to a vector and the transpose was done 
%to get the desired format of the vector `newdata`. You are welcome to 
%try the code without transpose and see what difference it makes.
```

Comment: Thank you for your appreciation.

Answer (score 3):

Your main "mistake" is that You are trying to reinvent the wheel.

The first step would be to get rid of the first column.

`B = A(:,2:end)`

And the final one would be to reshape the matrix:

`B = reshape(B.',1,[])'`

No need to write your own code. I think it's easier that way.

Comment: As `A` is a matrix it is not very robust to use `length`. I would recommend either `size(A,2)` or simply `end`.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is not by using nested loops. Matlab has tons of built in functionality that you should try to use.

try this:

```
newdata = A;
newdata(:,1) = [];     %this will eliminate the first column of data
newdata = newdata';    %convert the matrix into its transpose in preparation for the next step
newdata = newdata(:);  %automatically create the desired vector with this operator
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @pivovarit, you can simply use `reshape`. However, you may also want to note that since MATLAB stores numbers in a column major form, **if you in fact want to simply access the data linearly**, by setting, say `C`, as

```
C = A(:,2:end)'
```

you could simply call the elements as `C(1)`, `C(2)`, `C(6)`, etc, just as you would for the column vector.

Comment: As `A` is a matrix it is not very robust to use `length`. I would recommend either `size(A,2)` or simply `end`.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin: Yeah; my mistake. `end` is much better. Thanks. :)